# Update php via php-osx Liip mac os x

Tags: php, macos, operating-system

I have installed PHP via [php-osx Liip](http://php-osx.liip.ch) using:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4
```

The command line said that the instalation is Ok, but when I run `php -v` on terminal, the terminal displays the old version and the apache with `<?php phpinfo();` as well.

Do I have to change something for the new version be recognized

Comment: this helped me a lot: http://ziad.eljammal.com/install-php-5-5-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the commandline binary is in /usr/local/php5/bin/php, you have to directly call that.

You can also add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

to eg. your ~/.profile file to have it in your search path

Answer (score 3):

I think I have solved that

php-osx installs the php on /usr/loacl/php5 . So what I did:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

I've change the line

```
LoadModule php5_module  libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

to:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
```

The php version that's linked to apache updated, but the php version on terminal keeps the old one

If someone has another explanation, It would be nice